# Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.dll (MongoDB)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have .NET 8 project using `MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore v7.0.0-preview` and `MongoDB.Driver v2.24.0`.

I created my `MyDbContext` class inherited from the `DbContext` and in the `void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method performed all required attributes mapping.

But when I called `var drawings = db.Drawings.ToList();` I got the following exception:

> Exception thrown: `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException` in
> MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in
> MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.dll **The given key was not present in the
> dictionary**.

I checked all attributes binding. For example, binding the property `Name` looks like below:

```
b.Property(c => c.Name).HasElementName("name");
```

How can I understand what causes the exception? I tried to analyze the callback stack. But it doesn’t help a much and the `InnerException` is `null`.

I have a few collections and they are loaded without a problem. But this one thought the exception and I can’t understand why.

Thanks

Comment: _Once you have the source code, you have a solution_. I downloaded sources from the [https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-efcore-provider](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-efcore-provider). Debug version gave me detailed description what attribute causes the problem: _**Document does not contain value for non-nullable field 'ProgramName'.**_ A customer declared non-nullable attribute but not set a value for this field in the document.